# What is the probability of a pdf at a value?

Tags: probability, integration

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered but having trouble finding it. In a pdf, what is the correct formal (or even informal) answer for the probability at a point within the support for the pdf? One can integrate between equal bounds and obtain zero, but is the integral even a defined operation between equal bounds? One certainly can't call it zero (as my professor does), because even though it might be infinitesimally small it has to be nonzero (zero probability indicating an event cannot occur). Right?

Edit: Let me pose the question differently: if we have a pdf f,X and select a sample from that pdf x, is it logical to state that we have selected a sample that had and continues to have zero probability of being selected?

(Note: I'm not suggesting or implying a finite probability, that is clearly not possible.)

Comment: The definition of probability density function (pdf) implies that, if this function is defined at a point $x$, then the probability of $\{x\}$ is zero.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasBlass, but try to make your question more professional by removing “right?”, “I’m sure this has already been asked”, and maybe try not to write just a block of text. These are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability zero is the correct answer in this scenario. To see why, let us consider what would happen if this were not true with an example.

We will consider the simplest example of a pdf, the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Namely, we have that $f(x)=1$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Let $c$ be a point in $[0,1]$, and suppose that $P(x=c)=\varepsilon>0$.
Then we integrate over the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ and find that

$$P(x \in \mathbb{R}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx
= \int_0^1 1 \, dx = 1,$$
but we also get
$$P(x \in \mathbb{R}) = P(x \neq c) + P(x=c)
= \int_{-\infty}^c f(x) \, dx + \int_c^{\infty} f(x) \, dx + \varepsilon \\
= \int_0^c 1 \, dx + \int_c^1 1 \, dx + \varepsilon = 1 + \varepsilon > 1.$$

This is, of course, a contradiction.

Edit: I will also supplement this answer by remarking that this means that "probability $0$" and "cannot happen" are *not* the same thing, which is what has led you to this misapprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought answer. To clarify, I wasn't implying that the probability was greater than zero, only that undefined or defined through a limit seems a better answer than zero. Otherwise the probability of a point within the support equals the probability of a point outside the support. But it could be I don't understand set theory well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a definite integral with equal bounds is zero. We do have some requirements of the integrand (e.g. continuity), but these are satisfied for any well-behaved PDF. Hence, the probability of a point is zero. This may seem weird, but it is the natural result of a continuous probability distribution. To illustrate this, I'll use a non-rigorous explanation.

Consider the distribution of heights of people. This is a continuous distribution, as you can always 'zoom in' to get more accurate measurements. Supposed that you measured someone with a height of 2 followed by 1,000,000 decimal places of 0.This is still an approximation of their true height, and you could keep measuring further to add more decimal places. The probability that the infinite string of decimal places being 0 is also zero. Hence, the probability that the height of a person being *exactly* 2 metres would be zero.

Comment: If we took infinite samples from the distribution (obviously not directly applicable to heights), would we in theory eventually select the value in question?